# Is this a correct way to use Nested groupby in java8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following objects.

```
class RowData
{
  private List<RowCell> cells;
}

class RowCell
{
  private String headerName;
  private String value;
}
```

I have loaded the following CSV into these objects.

```
Country,Gender,Income
IND,M,23531
IND,F,2331
IND,M,2311
SNG,M,22111
HYD,F,20012
```

**What I need to do ?**

Find average income grouped by Country and gender.

**What have I done so far ?**

```
List<String> criteria = Arrays.asList("Country", "Gender", "Income");

List<RowData> rowDataStream = rows.stream().map(rowData -> new RowData(getMatchingCells(criteria, rowData))).collect(Collectors.toList());

// group by country
Map<String, List<RowData>> collect = rowDataStream.stream().collect(groupingBy(rowData -> rowData.getRowCells().get(0).getValue()));

// group everything above by gender now.
Map<Map<String, List<RowData>>, List<List<RowData>>> collect1 = collect.values().stream().collect(groupingBy(rowData -> rowData.stream().collect(groupingBy(o -> o.getRowCells().get(1).getValue()))));
```

**Questions**

1. Is this the right way to do it ?
2. It seems overly complex. Can you suggest a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you probably should load your data into meaningful DTOs / POJOs:

```
class Row {
    String country;
    String gender;
    int income;
    // Getters etc.
}
```

Then, given a `List<Row>`, you can simply do this:

```
Map<String, Double> groupedByCountry = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Row::getCountry, 
    Collectors.averagingInt(Row::getIncome)
)
```

```
Map<String, Double> groupedByGender = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Row::getGender, 
    Collectors.averagingInt(Row::getIncome)
)
```

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> groupedByCountryAndGender = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Row::getCountry, 
    Collectors.groupingBy(Row::getGender, 
    Collectors.averagingInt(Row::getIncome)
)
```

And for the structure you have given (list of `RowData` with `RowCell`s):

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> groupedByCountryAndGender = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.getCells().get(0).getValue(), 
    Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.getCells().get(1).getValue(), 
    Collectors.averagingInt(r -> Integer.valueOf(r.getCells().get(2).getValue()))
)
```

Comment: The columns that you see in the csv are for an example. It can contain any number of them. For this reason I created a row cell instead to have a better control over each cell.

Comment: Can you describe what is going wrong with the one I posted ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm honestly looking at your second `groupBy` and I have no idea what is happening. To group by gender + country at once I would better like this:

```java
final Map<Pair<String, String>, List<RowData>> collect = rowDataStream.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(rowData -> Pair.of(
        rowData.getCells().get(0).getValue(),
        rowData.getCells().get(1).getValue()
  )));
```

Pair is just a simple container for any two values, you can use apache commons pair, vavr tuple or create your own.

Answer (score 2):

Create a more logical grouping of data like :

```
class RowData {
    private String country;
    private String gender;
    private double income;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

And the data is contained in the following list:

```
List<RowData> rowDataList = Arrays.asList(new RowData("IND", "M", 23531), 
                new RowData("IND", "F", 2331), new RowData("IND", "M", 2331),
                new RowData("SNG", "M", 22111), new RowData("HUD", "F", 20012));
```

Now you can:

```
Map<String, Double> dataMap = rowDataList.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getCountry() + e.getGender(), 
                       Collectors.averagingDouble(RowData::getIncome)));
```

Comment: What if a country plus gender concatenation is equals to another concatenation?

Comment: Creating a nested map is much cleaner in my opinion. With concatenation you get keys like "INDM" and "INDF". This is bad to query.

Comment: I understand how concise is your snippet. I know how to do it this way but as soon as I nested my objects (create row cell to represent columns) I lost how to perform a grouping so I ended up writing such a big line of code. Can you suggest what can be done to my code to give the desired output without changing the pojos.